# Composition instead of inheritance in Controllers

Tags: sapui5

I'd like to implement a structure like below to avoid a "BaseController" superclass:

**controller/helpers/Navigation.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/base/Object"
], function(Object) {
    "use strict";

    return Object.extend("sap.cre.core.ui.controller.helpers.Navigation", {
        controller: null,

        onInit: function(controller) {
            this._controller = controller;
        },

        onNavBack: function() {
            this._controller.getRouter().navTo("home");
        }
    });
});
```

**controller/Something.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/cre/core/ui/controller/helpers/Navigation"
], function(Controller, Navigation) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.cre.core.ui.controller.Something", {
        onInit: function() {
            this.navigation = new Navigation(this);
        }
    });
});
```

Then the XML view is pointing the onPress event like below:

```
<semantic:FullscreenPage
        navButtonPress="navigation.onNavBack"
        showNavButton="true"> ...
```

But the view isn't finding the event when pointed to `navigation.`.

So, my questions are:

- has someone seen such approach over OpenUI5/SAPUI5 already?
- Is there any bad consequence?
- What is wrong in my approach that the view cannot call `navigation.onNavBack`?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I tried this way too:

**controller/Something.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/cre/core/ui/controller/helpers/Navigation"
], function(Controller, Navigation) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("sap.cre.core.ui.controller.Something", {
        navigation: new Navigation()
    });
});
```

That way works as @hirse suggested (putting a `.` in front of the path in the view), but that let me lose any link to the controller, which turns the helper class too limited and mostly useless.

But it makes me guess that just by setting `this.navigation = new Navigation(this)` it's missing anything about binding on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks interesting and I think it could be a good idea.

Now to your concrete problem:
You are missing a `.` in front of your handler function: `.navigation.onNavBack`

Quoting from the [Developer Guide](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe.html):

> - Names starting with a dot ('.') are always assumed to represent a method in the controller.
> - Names containing a dot at a later position are assumed to represent global functions
> - Names without dot are interpreted as a relative name; if nothing is found, they are interpreted as an absolute name.

Which means,
`onNavBack` will use the function in the controller if there is one and keep looking otherwise;
`.onNavBack` will expect a function in the controller;
`navigation.onNavBack` will **only** look for a global function;
`.navigation.onNavBack` is what you want to use.

Comment: hummm, when putting a `.` in the front, like `.onNavBack`, in fact it works; but when placing it in a namespace, such as `.navigation.onNavBack`, it still doesn't work, the same way.

if I declare `navigation` as an attribute, at the same level as `onInit`, it works as you suggested, which probably means that by setting `this.navigation`, it`s missing any binding procedure on the ran. Problem with that approach is that I miss any link to the controller itself, which stays useless for me :/

Comment: In the scope of the handler, `this` might be your Controller instance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following call cannot work:

```
this.navigation = new Navigation(this);
```

This can't work because your helper `sap.cre.core.ui.controller.helpers.Navigation` does not declare a constructor which could take the one parameter that you are passing (the reference to your controller). I guess you are assuming that `new Navigation(this);` will call your onInit(...) and due to some magic the reference to your controller is passed. But that's not right. Make sure to declare a constructor, see for [sap.ui.base.Object](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.Object.html) for details. In your case any call to `onNavBack` will lead to an error because your `this._controller` is `undefined`, right?

I have used a similar approach in the past together with sap.ui.define. But instead of returning sap.ui.base.Object.extend(...) I used native OO JavaScript...
That helped me to get rid of sap.ui.base.Object. However, you might have a good reason to keep that dependency...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is redefine the constructor of Navigation.js

```
constructor: function(controller) {
        this._controller = controller;
    },
```

Now you have a reference to the main controller...